# Android: JSON parsing error nothing comes up

Tags: java, android, json, mobile

I am trying to parse JSON, I have done it there before but not quiet this way. I spent hours trying to solve the problem, but I dont know what is wrong with the code.I am attaching the entire code for the activity, Web Request class and the layout. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I get this error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/users/sdp_engine_list.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-19 18:17:27.427 3450-3450/? W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-19 18:17:28.232 3450-3592/? W/DisplayManagerService: Failed to notify process 20004 that displays changed, assuming it died.
```

This is the activity Transactions class.

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import com.rectuca.iyzicodemo.Classes.Transaction;
import com.rectuca.iyzicodemo.Library.WebRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


    public class Transactions extends ListActivity {

        // URL to get contacts JSON
        private static String url = "http://www.mocky.io/v2/573dbd243700005f194dcdcc";

        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_PAYMENTS= "payments";
        private static final String TAG_PAYMENT_ID = "paymentId";
        private static final String TAG_SENT_BY = "sentBy";
        private static final String TAG_DATE_TIME = "dateTime";
        private static final String TAG_SENT_TO = "sentTo";
        private static final String TAG_BANK_NAME = "bankName";
        private static final String TAG_INSTALLMENTS = "installments";
        private static final String TAG_AMOUNT = "amount";
        private static final String TAG_3DS = "threeDs";
        private static final String TAG_CANCELLED = "cancelled";
        private static final String TAG_RETURNED = "returned";
        private static final String TAG_TRANSACTION_STATUS = "transactionStatus";
        private static final String TAG_BLOCKAGE_AMOUNT = "blockage_amount";
        private static final String TAG_BLOCKAGE_RELEASE_DATE = "blockageReleaseDate";


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_transactions);

// Calling async task to get json
            new GetInfo().execute();
        }
        /**
         * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
         */
        private class GetInfo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            // Hashmap for ListView
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> transactionInfoList;
            ProgressDialog proDialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
// Showing progress loading dialog
                proDialog = new ProgressDialog(Transactions.this);
                proDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
                proDialog.setCancelable(false);
                proDialog.show();
            }
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
// Creating service handler class instance
                WebRequest webReq = new WebRequest();

// Making a request to url and getting response
                String jsonStr = webReq.makeWebServiceCall(url, WebRequest.GET);

                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

                transactionInfoList = ParseJSON(jsonStr);

                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void requestresult) {
                super.onPostExecute(requestresult);
// Dismiss the progress dialog
                if (proDialog.isShowing())
                    proDialog.dismiss();
/**
 * Updating received data from JSON into ListView
 * */
                transactionInfoList=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        Transactions.this, transactionInfoList,
                        R.layout.row_layout, new String[]{TAG_SENT_TO,TAG_DATE_TIME
                        ,TAG_BANK_NAME,TAG_AMOUNT,TAG_3DS, TAG_CANCELLED,
                        TAG_RETURNED},
                        new int[]{R.id.name,R.id.dateTime ,R.id.bankName,R.id.amount,
                        R.id.threeDS, R.id.cancelled, R.id.returned});

                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }

        }
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ParseJSON(String json) {
            if (json != null) {
                try {
// Hashmap for ListView
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> paymentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);

// Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray payments = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_PAYMENTS);

// looping through All Payments
                    for (int i = 0; i < payments.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = payments.getJSONObject(i);

                        String dateTime =c.getString(TAG_DATE_TIME);
                        String sentTo =c.getString(TAG_SENT_TO);
                        String bankName =c.getString(TAG_BANK_NAME)+" ( "+c.getString(TAG_INSTALLMENTS)+" ) " ;
                        String amount =c.getString(TAG_AMOUNT);
                        String threeDS =c.getString(TAG_3DS);
                        String cancelled =c.getString(TAG_CANCELLED);
                        String returned =c.getString(TAG_RETURNED);



// temporary hashmap for a single payment
                        HashMap<String, String> payment = new HashMap<String, String>();

// adding every child node to HashMap key => value
                        payment.put(TAG_DATE_TIME, dateTime);
                        payment.put(TAG_SENT_TO, sentTo);
                        payment.put(TAG_BANK_NAME, bankName);
                        payment.put(TAG_AMOUNT, amount);
                        payment.put(TAG_3DS, threeDS);
                        payment.put(TAG_CANCELLED, cancelled);
                        payment.put(TAG_RETURNED, returned);






// adding student to students list
                        paymentList.add(payment);
                    }
                    return paymentList;
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "No data received from HTTP Request");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the WebRequest Class

```
package com.rectuca.iyzicodemo.Library;
        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.BufferedWriter;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.io.OutputStream;
        import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
        import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
        import java.net.URL;
        import java.net.URLEncoder;
        import java.util.HashMap;
        import java.util.Map;

        import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class WebRequest {

    static String response = null;
    public final static int GET = 1;
    public final static int POST = 2;

    //Constructor with no parameter
    public WebRequest() {

    }

    /**
     * Making web service call
     *
     * @url - url to make request
     * @requestmethod - http request method
     */
    public String makeWebServiceCall(String url, int requestmethod) {
        return this.makeWebServiceCall(url, requestmethod, null);
    }

    /**
     * Making service call
     *
     * @url - url to make request
     * @requestmethod - http request method
     * @params - http request params
     */
    public String makeWebServiceCall(String urladdress, int requestmethod,
                                     HashMap<String, String> params) {
        URL url;
        String response = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(urladdress);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            if (requestmethod == POST) {
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            } else if (requestmethod == GET) {
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            }

            if (params != null) {
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                boolean first = true;
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                    if (first)
                        first = false;
                    else
                        result.append("&");

                    result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                    result.append("=");
                    result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
                }

                writer.write(result.toString());

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
            }

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += line;
                }
            } else {
                response = "";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }

}
```

This is what I am trying to do

http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/JqcySZU2Pz067NutlDvPP5Zq_3n_WSAllIuEdjQjOjyeGkKguaMNCrltaKbjBCi16g=h900-rw

Comment: Post the minimal code we need dude, nobody is going to scroll through 200+ lines of code. It's very rude also. You cannot take the time to single out what's important? Fine, I won't take the time to try and help you. Why the hell would we need layout if it's a problem in the code. Also, you didn't explain the error you're getting,

Comment: Sorry for that, but as nothing shows up on the screen and the Exception it gives is very irrelevant and changing. I don't know which part might be wrong. But I will edit it and add the Exception and reduce the amount of code

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use 
VOLLEY networking library by google

You should try to use Volley JSONOBJECTREQUEST() and you won't have any issue after that parsing will be easier.

add this to dependency section of your app

```
 dependencies {
      compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
  }
```